# Help with clarifying UR10e center of mass

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, dynamics, arm-kinematics

I'm doing an assignment related to the Universal Robot UR10e robot for a robotics class. I have to use the center of mass of each link to solve the problem. I found the information on the link below (on the right of the DH table):
https://www.universal-robots.com/articles/ur/application-installation/dh-parameters-for-calculations-of-kinematics-and-dynamics/

However, I'm not sure which coordinate frame is used for each center of mass point? For each link is the center of mass coordinate with respect to the coordinate frame at the start of the link? For example, for link 2 is the center of mass with respect to the DH frame 1? Or are the center of mass with respect to the DH frame at the end of the link? Someone else asked a similar question on the UR10e's forum website back in June, but no one has answered them. I tried calling one of universal robot's US offices and left a voicemail, but no one has called me back.